# How to get max size of a single value in a column in Sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to find the max size of one value in a column. Like if we have column name with firstName . I need to know maximum number of bytes size of the first Name.

Comment: max allowed `firstName` size in column or max available `firstName` size in column?

Comment: I am confident one of those duplicates is the answer to your question; which is unclear (hence why I have added both).

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the maximum length of a column, you can use the `LEN` function which returns the length of a string and then use the `MAX` function to return the maximum value in a set of values. Here is the sample.

```
SELECT MAX(LEN(column_name)) FROM table_name
```

If you want the maximum number of bytes, you can use the `DATALENGTH` function which returns the number of bytes used to represent an expression. Note that this function counts both leading and trailing spaces when calculating the length of the expression.

```
SELECT MAX(DATALENGTH(column_name)) FROM table_name
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the length of longest first name in a table you can count the characters of each one and then take the max value.

For example:

```
select max(len(first_name)) from my_table
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cae82230026bbab676cadb5c22fa5a2a).